# windows bitmap print driver, windbg, symbols unires.dll

Tags: windows, printing, driver, windbg

How I debug a bitmap print driver taken from the sample at
 https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/bitmap

Currently I have been doing this but surely there is a better way:

1) Build the solution in debug mode.

2) Install it as a driver with .inf file.

3) Copy the PDB file to the C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\x64\3 folder.

4) Attach Visual studio to spool.exe and print any document

5) This is OK but any changes made to the code even for testing purposes will not work. I have to reinstall the driver, copy the pdb file again.

I have tried another way also
1) Attach the printer to FILE: port print to file

2) Attach windgb to notepad and print

3) But I don't see all symbols loaded

4) I tried .symfyx, reload /f. This says that UNIRES.dll cannot be loaded.

I was able to attach windbg to notepad.exe. Do I need UNIRES.DLL to be able to use unidrv!giDebugLevel

Please suggest what ways do you follow to debug the driver?

Comment: doesnt attaching to wudfhost.exe work as documented  and you shouldn't be required to copy pdb files  if you have _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable set

Comment: @blabb: What is wudfhost.exe?

Comment: @blabb: I wish you posted what document you are talking about rather than saying "as documented". Are you just imaging some documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/debugging-printer-driver-components. Thats what I follow and there is no reference to wudfhost

Comment: sorry i was mistaken PrinterDriver is not an UMDF driver so [wudfhost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/enabling-a-debugger) does not apply

Comment: @blabb: Thank you. I got it use giDebugLevel =1 and write verbose log to DbgView. It kind of OK. Since I am not a driver developer this whole world is fuzzy.

Answer (score -1):

use LPT1 for add on a printer choose settings and set them at  some binary data numbers im sitting on a phone atm cant remember exact how but choose your printer and add the LPT1 port for it even if its a usb one, add the communication device and lpt1,
or am i the hero that doesnt read lol